# If I cancel a PS+ subscription, will I still have access to downloaded saves from the cloud?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

So, I borrowed a friend’s PS4 in order to play an exclusive game and I loved it so much that I went out and bought my own PS4 so I could play the game more. I know you have to have a PlayStation Plus membership to transfer over save data, but I’m wondering if once I download that save data to my new PS4 if it will stay there if I cancel the PS+ subscription? I’m not very tech-savvy and I’m having trouble finding the answer to this question anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling your PS+ subscription will not affect save files on your PS4 hard drive.

You don't need PS+ to transfer save data per say, you only need it to back up save data to the cloud.

You can transfer the data from your friends PS4 with a USB stick and you won't ever need to worry about PS+.

If you have already managed to get your save files from the cloud on to your PS4 hard drive they will not be affected by the PS+ subscription. (Other than no longer being periodically backed up to the cloud)

Also worth noting is that save files are tied to your PSN account so you will need use the same account that you played the game on originally otherwise the save files will not transfer. Hopefully you created your own account when you borrowed the PS4.